# UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ' '

Tags: java, tostring

First, thank you for spending some time on this problem. I've tried based on my own knowledge but can not find out where to modify. I have made a game and in the end, I have to return the formatted string to the terminal.

The exception appeared when I change basic string concatenation to the formatted string. I don't know how to fix it.

1. `players` is the player array.
2. `WinRatio` is `score`(int) divided by `gamePlayed`(int), rounding to integer.

Here is part of my code.

```
public static void searchAndPrintRankingDataDesc() {
    NimPlayer [] players = NimPlayer.getPlayer();
    Arrays.sort(players, Comparator.comparing((NimPlayer::getWinRatio)).reversed().thenComparing(NimPlayer::getUserName));
    Arrays.stream(players).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And my toString method:

```
public String getWinRatio() {
    return Integer.toString(Math.round(Float.valueOf(getScore())/ (getGamePlayed())*100));
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format( "%02d" +"% | "+ "%02d" +" games | "+ "%s " + "%s", getWinRatio(), gamePlayed, givenName, familyName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is another popped out for illegerConversion. And I change `getWinRatio` back to int type. Problem solved. Thanks @Renato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

% is a special character for String.format, to escape %, you will have to replace it with %%. So your statement becomes-

```
String.format( "%02d" +"%% | "+ "%02d" +" games | "+ "%s " + "%s", getWinRatio(), gamePlayed, givenName, familyName);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `%` in the formatted string, it has to be escaped using another `%`. And when formatting the integer value, it will get `IllegalFormatConversionException` if there has already a toString method.

This code here formatted the integer to string.

```
public String getWinRatio() {
return Integer.toString(Math.round(Float.valueOf(getScore())/ (getGamePlayed())*100));
```

}

And the code below formatted again, causing `IllegalFormatConversionException`.

```
public String toString() {
return String.format( "%02d" +"% | "+ "%02d" +" games | "+ "%s " + "%s", getWinRatio(), gamePlayed, givenName, familyName);
```

}

So, the answer will be:

```
public int getWinRatio() {
    return Math.round(Float.valueOf(getScore())/ (getGamePlayed())*100);
}
public String toString() {
    return String.format( "%02d" +"%%" + " | "+ "%02d" +" games | "+ "%s " + "%s", getWinRatio(), gamePlayed, givenName, familyName);
}
```